# Is this correct and if so how can we justify it? (Exchanging sums/derivatives)

Tags: real-analysis

$$-\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} x(1-\zeta)^{x-1}=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{d}{d\zeta}(1-\zeta)^x\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{d}{d\zeta}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} (1-\zeta)^x$$

Can anyone explain if switching the derivative and sum is allowed here and if it is give me a rough explanation/intuition as to why it is true?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Could you give me some rough idea (I'm not after pure rigour at the moment) why this is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gnomic answer is that the derivative is a linear operator on functions.

But you can really see this from the definition of derivative:

$$(f+g)'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(f+g)(x+h)-(f+g)(x)}h = $$
$$ = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(f(x+h)+g(x+h)-f(x)-g(x))(x)}h $$
$$ = \lim_{h\to 0} \left[\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h +\frac{g(x+h)-f(x)}h \right]$$
$$ = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h +\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x+h)-f(x)}h$$
$$ = f'(x) + g'(x)$$

And if this is true for the sum of two functions, it is true for an arbitrary number of terms by finite induction.

Answer (score 0):

Your work is correct. The main intuition behind this is that the *variable* on which the **summation is being carried out** and the *variable* with respect to which **the sum is being differentiated** are different, or in other words, *independent*.